# How do I make sure the Arduino only run this line of code once even after reset?

Tags: arduino, arduino-c++, real-time-clock

I have a real-time Clock module and I'm trying to make an RGB Clock out of it. There is a particular line of code that sets the time and date to the real-time clock module. I put this in the setup code but every time I reset the Arduino it runs that line of code again. Is there any way that I can make sure that once this line in of code is run it will never run again even if I reset the Arduino?

Comment: If you need to have an actual clock, this is solved by hardware, having an external RTC circuit and a battery. Apart from that, most modern MCUs have the possibility to check reset cause. If you have that option, check if reset was caused by Power-on reset or something else.

Comment: Thanks, I can't believe I didn't think of this earlier!!

Answer (score 3):

It is a broad question which goes beyond programming. The answer to your concrete problem is "Remove that line of code" from `setup`, it will not run (I am sure you know this). However, you should provide some physical input (buttons + rudimentary menu-like interface) to set the clock on first usage. A second way of setting the  time can be a serial port to which you can physically connect. This requires some code to read that serial port in your `loop` method.

In the release version of you Clock firmware I would leave just reading the time stored in EEPROM (from RTC module or an external chip), not the hard-coded value in `setup`.

Comment: Hardware solutions in programming are always the best ones :)

Answer (score 0):

Your RTC might have a bit saying "RTC stopped", which you might use to switch to "normal behavior". It will be set when removing power and the RTC-battery. The RTC will probably read "1-Jan-1970 00:00" then, and won't increment unless set.

However, your demo code to set the RTC is just demo code, not intended to really use as is. (See Victor's response for more details)